# Convert " 24OCT2020:00:00:00" format into datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, python-datetime

I have column of strings as  `24OCT2020:00:00:00`. I want to convert it to date-time. I have tried -
`data["START_DATE"] = pd.to_datetime(data["START_DATE"])` but getting following error -
`ParserError: Unknown string format: 24OCT2020:00:00:00`. Help me in this regard.

Answer (score 3):

Add parameter `format` with `%d%b%Y:%H:%M:%S` for match `ddmmmyyyy:HH:MM:SS`, for months is use `%b` for first 3 letters of months names:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'START_DATE':['24OCT2020:00:00:00','25OCT2020:00:00:00']})
data["START_DATE"] = pd.to_datetime(data["START_DATE"], format='%d%b%Y:%H:%M:%S')
print (data)
  START_DATE
0 2020-10-24
1 2020-10-25
```